# passing 2D arrays to c++ function as memory block using "address of" operator

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

For passing 2D arrays to C++ function is there a way to pass as a whole block of memory as:

```
void functionname(double (&arrayname)[10][10])
```

For this function definition, what would be the function prototype and function call?

The most frequent ways are

```
**arrayname
(*arrayname)[columns]
arrayname[][columns]
```

But passing as memory block looks rarely used.

Comment: See [array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay)

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you mean that you want to pass an arbitrary "block" of doubles as a `double[10][10]` to that function, or do you mean something else?

Comment: templates can use this sort of construction to instantiate functions having different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
void functionname(double (&arrayname)[10][10]) { ... }
```

BTW, the  `&` in the function declaration is not the addressof operator. It defines a reference type.

The following program should build successfully.

```
void functionname(double (&arrayname)[10][10])
{
}

int main()
{
   double a[10][10];
   functionname(a);
}
```

The only downside of using such a function declaration is that you cannot use an array that does not match both the dimensions precisely. You cannot use

```
   double a[20][10];  // Size mismatch.
   functionname(a);
```

---

The use of

```
void functionname(double **arrayname);
void functionname(double (*arrayname)[10]);
void functionname(double arrayname[][10]);
```

have their purpose but, more importantly, they are not equivalent.

For the sake simplifying the answer, Let say you have different names.

```
void function_one(double **arrayname);
void function_two(double (*arrayname)[10]);
void function_three(double arrayname[][10]);
```

and you have the following four types of objects.

```
double** array_one;
double (*array_two)[10];
double* array_three[10];
double array_foure[10][10];

// Assume array_one, array_two and array_three are properly initialized.
```

Then,

```
function_one(array_one);      // OK.
function_one(array_two);      // Not OK. array_two does not decay to double**
function_one(array_three);    // OK. array_three decays to double**
function_one(array_four);     // Not OK. array_four does not decay do double**

function_two(array_one);      // Not OK. array_one cannot be converted to double (*)[10]
function_two(array_two);      // OK.
function_two(array_three);    // Not OK. array_three cannot be converted to double (*)[10]
function_two(array_four);     // Not OK. array_four cannot be converted to double (*)[10]
function_two(&array_four[0]); // OK. array_four[0] is type double [10].
                              // &array_four[0] is of type double (*)[10].

function_three(array_one);    // Not OK.
function_three(array_two);    // Not OK.
function_three(array_three);  // Not OK.
function_three(array_four);   // OK.
```

In conclusion, the functions are similar in that they allow you to work with 2D arrays but it's necessary to understand how they are different so they can used correctly.

Comment: For dynamic binding such as memory/array allocated using "new" or "malloc" can I use the technique 

void functionname(double (&arrayname)[10][10]) { ... }